# how to Loop through an array with a custom key

Tags: php, arrays

How can I loop through an array with a custom key:

```
$sql = "Select * from Users";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $db);

$rows = array();
while($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $rows['customKey'] = array(0, 1, 2, 3);
 $rows[] = $list;
}
```

Then I pass this to another array

```
foreach($rows as $row) {
 $array = array (
  'test' => $row,
  'test2' => $row['userName'] 
)
}
```

Then I print $array

```
print_r($array['test']);
```

returns

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [userName] => John Smith )
```

why is it not getting $rows['customKey'] here.

Note: I know i need to stop using mysql_* .. this is a legacy application.

Comment: What do you want the array to look like?

Comment: @AbraCadaver I want to be able to pass $row['customKey'] to $array in the foreach loop

Comment: Are you sure you don't want it to look like `Array ( [id] => 1 [userName] => John Smith [customKey] => (0, 1, 2, 3) )`?

Comment: @silentw if you mean Array ( [id] => 1 [userName] => John Smith [customKey] => Array ([0] => 0 [1] => 1) ) then yes, i can extract what I need from there with $array['test']['customKey'][0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your line:

```
$rows['customKey'] = array(0, 1, 2, 3);
```

to:

```
$list['customKey'] = array(0, 1, 2, 3);
```